# Need Driver solution for RT8723BS WLAN

Tags: networking, drivers

I am working with a non profit project who needs to run some survey on the field and needs to use Ubuntu. In Bangladesh (that is where I am from) we have a brand called i-Life who sells cheap laptops made in China. This laptop's WLAN is Realtek RT8723BS and Sound card is Intel SST Audio Device with ES8316 AudCodec. This is how they looks on Windows.

[image: WLAN].

Now for this RT8723BS I have follwed some instructions online to get the drives from GIT and compile it, but seems like the make command is not working for some reason. This is the output I get:

```
root@ZED-AIR:/usr/local/src/rtl8723bs# make
root@ZED-AIR:/usr/local/src/rtl8723bs# make install
root@ZED-AIR:/usr/local/src/rtl8723bs# sudo depmod -a
root@ZED-AIR:/usr/local/src/rtl8723bs# sudo modprobe r8723bs
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8723bs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic
root@ZED-AIR:/usr/local/src/rtl8723bs#
```

I have also tried to downlaod and install the `rtl8723bs-dkms_4.4.1+17245.20160325.2_all.deb` from the launchpad link, but when I try to install that, it says "dkms not installed" Then when I try to install dkms, it doesn't work.

So can anyone please help me?

Comment: I think you mistyped. shouldn't the module be "rt8723bs" or "rtl8723bs"? To get dkms type `sudo apt-get install dkms`

Comment: Correct, RTL but either way, it doens't work.

Comment: make sure to check the .o file created once you complete your make and type the load the same module, if it does have the same name and even after that if it shows no module found then check the directory "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic".

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late but for the record:
The deb file you tried to use (4.4.1...) is the one Intel distributes with their compute stick.  You should be using the (4.3.5.5... version) distributed with the ubuntu releases with its firmware included the linux-firmware package.  The 4.15 kernel in Ubuntu 18.04 should allow networking to work, but it takes a 4.19 kernel for bluetooth to work.